# Magento2 : How to translate input value in html template

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, i18n

I try to translate the value attribute of an input

```
<input type="checkbox" id="html" name="fav_language" data-bind="i18n: {value:'Check here'}">
```

I tried something like that but it doesn't work

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found the solution :**
Add a label and translate it, can't directly do it inside input

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox_id" value="value">
<label for="checkbox_id" data-bind="i18n: 'Sign In'"></label>
```